# BufferedWriter - already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, file, bufferedwriter

After I used the BufferedWriter the second time I start the Java Standalone Application (over Eclipse IDE neon) it gives me this exception:

> Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-174]
>   Error Code: 90020

```
    File file = new File(".testfile");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(myString);
        bw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

I am pretty sure that this doesn't close the writer correctly. What should I do to prevent this exception?

Edit: (doesn't work with resources)

```
public void writeKeyToFile(String key) {
    File file = new File(".license");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(licensekey);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use try with resources.

Comment: @hover still doesn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your question is confusing -- you're showing basic use of a BufferedWriter wrapping a FileWriter, but the error is mentioning something totally different, a JdbcSQLException related to use of a database. Are you sure that you're barking up the right tree here? Also fyi, you're not showing code that uses try-with-resources above.